# Android: Tap phones to exchange information without NFC

Tags: java, android

I would like to develop a application that when used between two phone we can send exchange data(like e-visiting card). I intend to develop it for all smart phones even those without NFC. I am just a budding developer and would like to have some references about the possibilities of such an app. i have seen BUMP but i do not intend to maintain any server and would like to create a temporary network between the two phones and terminate it after the transfer. So is there any possibility in developing such an app? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the size of the data, but one possibility that comes to mind is the use of QR codes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

You could try using a library like zxing (https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) to generate the qr codes.

Basically the phone wanting to send the data generates a qr code representation than the phone wanting to read the data reads the qr code with its camera and translates back to the original data.

Comment: No i just want to send a e-visiting card at the tap of phones by creating a temporary private network between the two phones

Comment: the size may be 1 kb or so

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use bluetoolth or local area network.
I pefer LAN.
In your app , you can set one app as server, another app as client.
make a socket connection and send your data.

Comment: I dont want to use bluetooth..i just wanna create a temporary private network(just like bluetooth)

Comment: If you dont use bluetooth or NFC or net server, the only way you can try is LAN.

Comment: Can LAN be shared between two mobiles? I've heard about WIFI direct but that can only be done through SDK v14. I also want it to work for android 2.3 and android currently is not supporting adhoc networks